# Copy and paste to next available row powershell to excel

Tags: excel, powershell, copy, paste

Trying to copy and paste to next available row in sheet(Running Averages), not sure on the powershell code to use the next available row in my code below all is working other than it going to the next available row. Any help is appreciated.

````
 $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Users\caw013\UMB\GRP_Corporate Security Share_Corporate Security - Documents\Daily Reports\Daily Report Master Test - Do Not Modify.xlsm')
 $Excel.Visible = $True
 #$conn = $Workbook.Connections
 #$Workbook.RefreshAll()
 #while($conn | ForEach-Object {if($_.OLEDBConnection.Refreshing){$true}}){
    #Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
 #} 
$excel.Run('Sheet1.copyCountstoday')
$Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item(“Daily Report”)
$worksheet.activate() 
$range = $WorkSheet.Range(“H14:O16”)
$range.Copy() | out-null
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.item("Running Averages")
$Range = $Worksheet.Range(“A7:H1048576”)
$Worksheet.Paste($range)
#Excel.Quit()
#Remove-Variable -Name excel```
````

Comment: You probably need to check the Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows property to see how many rows are in use, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just doing VBA instead of using powershell to copy and paste to next available row